# OpenID and OAuth Terminologies List

Tags: openid, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth, google-oauth, yahoo-oauth

I would like to ask a **complete terminology of OpenId and OAuth**. It seems like there are a lot of terms when it is only used the same way. For example,

- Client ID is equivalent to oauth_consumer_key (maybe a lot more).
- Another thing is for the OpenID, what is the term for the URL that is being used aside from OpenID?

The terms are very very confusing and it would really help a lot if there is some kind of a thesaurus just for this. It would help because just by reading one article, my brain goes nationwide when searching for the right terms. It pauses. Then thinks like... Wait, am I thinking of the right thing?

I'm talking about OpenId and OAuth in general: Google, Facebook, Yahoo, Twitter, StackExchange, etc.

Comment: have you looked at there specifications? they are more or less similar http://openid.net/developers/specs/ ,http://oauth.net/about/

Comment: I know. But, what I am saying is, like for example, the articles that you have given me above are about OpenID. But, I'm talking about the terms. Like these examples of articles that you have given for instance, I can not see the term `Client ID` anywhere in your given article. Yet, it is being used by Google when you create a Client ID. But, on OAuth Playground, it says `oauth_consumer_key`. So, it is confusing. And on OAuth page, they use the term `API`, I can not see anywhere that says `API key`. But the term is being used by Facebook. I mean, which is which?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a purpose-built glossary other than searching google/wikipedia.

You may be getting tripped up by vendor-specific auth mechanisms, like API Keys that are not part of any spec. Every service usually has a combination of proprietary and spec compliant stuff.

You may balk at the RFCs, but they do try to define terms usually.

Other than the RFCs, there is no general purpose terminology. Every vendor can choose to document their services in the way they choose. Different services call their tokens different thing for various reasons specific to them. A grasp of the roles involved and how they function is better than knowing how to translate terms across services. The roles usually don't change.

Here's the OAuth stuff

OAuth1 RFC [rfc5849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849)

OAuth2 RFCs [rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)  [rfc6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)

Internet Security Glossary [rfc4949](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4949)